# Auto increment primary key data oracle

Tags: oracle

```
create or replace trigger t_user_privilege_pk 
befor insert on user_privilege
for each row

begin 
  IF NOT rep_global.rep_fire_trigger 
  THEN 
    RETURN; 
  END IF;  

  select EMAIL_LIST_ID_SEQ.nextval 
  into :new.EMAIL_LIST_ID 
  from  dual; 
end;
```

What is the meaning of, and why do we use, this type of syntax?

```
"IF NOT rep_global.rep_fire_trigger 
THEN 
RETURN;"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is custom code, could be anything.

Based on the name and location, `REP_GLOBAL` is a package, and `REP_FIRE_TRIGGER` is a boolean variable that controls whether the trigger should handle assigning PK values based on a sequence.

In a replicated (`REP_`) copy of the database, you do not want this behaviour and should be disabled, because you typically need the exact copy of the data, so I guess the `REP_FIRE_TRIGGER` is set to false in such a database.